# SharePoint Online - How to modify "Send email when Ownership is changed" settings using csom?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, csom, sharepoint-online

In my project I have to change the list setting using CSOM. The setting which I need to modify is "Send email when Ownership is changed"

I was not able to find a property or method in CSOM to modify this settings.

Is there any option available to update this settings?